# Starting activity when screen goes on

Tags: android

This is my scenario:

I need to start an activity when screen goes on, no problem, just it works slow(take a second at least).

So what I did is start the activity when screen goes of, and just wait till user turn his screen.

Now my problem is that the activity opens the lock screen, which is what I want, but it makes the unlock sound when screen goes of. Is there a possibility to cancel the sound? Or maybe make the activation when screen on work faster?

Comment: I dont see how taking a second is that bad :| Things take time to load.

Answer (score 0):

The onPause() and onResume() methods are called when the app brought to the background and into the foreground again, so just call the below function in onPause().

```
public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
  ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
  if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
}
```

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"

you have to add this permission to android manifest file

Comment: code is fine and works with android< 4.4, but wont work on kitkat

Answer (score -2):

You can use  ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF intents for screen off and screen on case. The below link will give you more idea about this

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/